# bad interpreter: no such file or directory on some files, but not all

Tags: python, shebang, github-codespaces

I have two python scripts in the same folder that I am trying to run in a Github Codespace.

I used `which python3` and my output is `/opt/python/<python version>/bin/python3`. I am using the symlink `stable` instead of `<python version>` to make my scripts a bit more installation agnostic.

When I add the she-bang `#!/opt/python/stable/bin/python3` to one of my files, everything is executed as expected, but when I use the same she-bang on a different file in the same directory, it doesn't work and I get the following error:

> bad interpreter: no such file or directory

Any ideas? I can't seem to find much about this behavior online.

Comment: Check for DOS newlines. A file saved in Windows format has a carriage return at the end of each line but the last, and you may have a `python3` executable, but you probably don't have a `python3$'\r'` executable.

Comment: Use `dos2unix filename.py` to fix it if that's the problem.

Comment: One thing you can do to validate that is to compare `head -n1 working.py | xxd` and `head -n1 broken.py | xxd`. If you have an extra byte of output in the broken case (ending with `0d 0a` instead of just `0a`), there's your problem.

Comment: Thanks, y'all were correct `dos2unix` fixed the problem.

Comment: Great. I'm closing this as a duplicate of some other questions about the same problem -- it's not python in the shebang in the duplicates, but the cause is the same and the solution the same regardless.